# Firestore 'Invalid query'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I make the following query:

```sql
db.collection("XXX")
                .whereField("place", isEqualTo: selectedPlace)
                .whereField("peoples", in: selectedPeoples)
                .whereField("price", isLessThan: priceUpperValue)
                .whereField("price", isGreaterThan: priceLowerValue)
                .order(by: "date", descending: true)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid query. You have a
where filter with an inequality (lessThan, lessThanOrEqual,
greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqual) on field 'price' and so you must
also use 'price' as your first queryOrderedBy field, but your first
queryOrderedBy is currently on field 'date' instead.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't have an ordering on a field that's different than your range filter.  Your ordering is on "date", but your range filter is on "price".  That's not allowed.

I suggest reviewing the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations):

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field.